# How to submit a Dataflow job from a jar?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow

For reproducibility I want to be able to build jars containing dataflow jobs and then run them with different parameters (e.g. promote them through different accounts). This will also simplify rolling back because builds will be immutable.

I am currently running jobs with the `DataflowPipelineRunner` from maven but this is terrible for the above reasons with automated deployments etc.

How can I directly run a dataflow job from a jar?

Answer (score 2):

Ah it looks like I need [templates](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/overview).

Answer (score 2):

I think template is the most promising way to go, but currently if you want to write a batch job to write to BigQuery, you need to create a template every time you want to run a job, which almost ruins the benefit of template.
(This is explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/templates/creating-templates))

As written in [this Github README](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowSDK-examples), you can create a bundle jar by calling `mvn package` then something like below should work to submit a dataflow job using the jar file.

```
java -cp target/google-cloud-dataflow-java-examples-all-bundled-manual_build.jar \
com.google.cloud.dataflow.examples.WordCount \
--project=<YOUR CLOUD PLATFORM PROJECT ID> \
--stagingLocation=<YOUR CLOUD STORAGE LOCATION> \
--runner=BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner
```

This is the way I currently choose, since I need to interact with BigQuery.